# How call callback in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have declared function:

```
 _translate(value: T, callback: (name: T) => T): void;
```

And function is:

```
public _translate(value: T, callback: T) {
    if (!this.translate) {
      callback(value);
    }
}
```

How to call(use) it? I tried the foLlowing:

```
this._translate(value, function(data: T) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

It does not work

Comment: You say you declare the function, where ? Is should be defined as  `public _translate(value: T, callback: (name: T) => T) { .. }`

Comment: You need to include more of your code if you want a good answer.  Please look at what constitutes a [mcve].

Comment: Without knowing more, it looks like your `callback` parameter should be a function that takes an input of type `T` and returns an output of type `T`.  But the function you are using does not return anything; it just logs to the console.  So either your declaration is wrong (should be `(name: T)=>void`) or your function is wrong (should end with `return data;`).  These are guesses based on your code snippets.  A better answer might be available with more information from you.

Comment: Okay see snippet here: `goo.gl/zqThvj`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not returning anything in your callback function, and you are not trying to use the result of your callback function from the caller... so, it *looks* like you should change the declaration of `_translate` to

```
_translate(value: T, callback: (name: T) => void): void;
```

That means the `callback` parameter should be a function which takes an input of type `T` and doesn't return anything (`void`).  Then, you need to change the implementation signature to match:

```
public _translate(value: T, callback: (name: T) => void): void {
    if (!this.translate) {
      callback(value);
    }
}
```

and then you should be able to call `_translate()` as a method on an instance of your class, like:

```
// class with _translate() method is MapperServiceArray<T>
const thingy = new MapperServiceArray<string>(); 

// call _translate on the object with a string and a callback that 
// takes a string and does not return a value
thingy._translate("something", x => console.log(x.charAt(0)));
```

---

Now that I see your [code snippet](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20IMapperServiceArray%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_translate%28value%3A%20T%2C%20callback%3A%20%28name%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20T%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_call%28%29%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MapperServiceArray%3CT%3E%20implements%20IMapperServiceArray%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Apublic%20_translate%28value%3A%20any%3A%20T%2C%20callback%3A%20%28T%20%3D%3E%20T%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21this.translate%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callback%28value%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Apublic%20_call%28%29%7B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Athis._translate%28value%3A%20any%2C%20%28data%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28data%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20mapperArray%20%3D%20new%20MapperServiceArray%3CISubjectBase%3E%28%29%3B), I can [suggest changes](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20IMapperServiceArray%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_translate%28value%3A%20T%2C%20callback%3A%20%28name%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20void%29%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_call%28%29%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MapperServiceArray%3CT%3E%20implements%20IMapperServiceArray%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20_translate%28value%3A%20T%2C%20callback%3A%20%28name%3A%20T%29%3D%3Evoid%29%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20what%20are%20you%20trying%20to%20do%20here%3F%20%20What%27s%20this.translate%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21this.translate%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callback%28value%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20_call%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20what%20are%20you%20trying%20to%20do%20here%3F%20%20What%27s%20value%3F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._translate%28value%2C%20data%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28data%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20thingy%20%3D%20new%20MapperServiceArray%3Cstring%3E%28%29%3B%0D%0Athingy._translate%28%22something%22%2C%20x%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28x.charAt%280%29%29%29%3B) that make it compile (sort of), but I really don't know what you're trying to do.  Hope that helped a bit.  Good luck.

Comment: And how to call this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// parameters: 
//   value, instance of T.
//   callback: function, accepting parameter (name) that is instance of T and returns object that is instance of T.
// returns: Void.
public _translate(value: T, callback: (name:T) => T): void {

}
```

and then to call it:

```
this._translate(value, (data: T): T => {
    return {};
});
```

Comment: But what is wrong here: `public _translate(value: T, callback: T) {
    if (!this.translate) {
      callback(value);
    }`

Comment: On the line: `callback(value); ` ?

Comment: On your case I get `:any` not assignable to T type

Comment: Try now. It's been a while since writing TS.

Comment: Does not work, seems I wrong in `_translate(value: T, callback: T);`

Comment: The above code is not valid TypeScript.  I think you might need to try things out in a TypeScript compiler ([here's one](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//)) if you're going to suggest code

Comment: I apologize. I just edited the code. It should be valid now.

Comment: It has problem in line: `this._translate(value, (data: T): T => {...` Error message is:  funciton must return value

Comment: Do you have a `return` statement inside the function? Should the callback be returning something? That's the way you have it written.

Comment: No function does not return but has callback: look: `public _translate(value: T, callback: (name: T) => T): void {}`